# Need to retrieve values from config file using array

Tags: c#, console

I have a static class which has static variables with automatic property of the keys in app config file . I need to assign the values from the config file to those variables using for loop /contains functionality

```
statics class sample
{
  public static string key1
  { get; set; }
}
```

-- Note I don't have access to the codes now for me to post it here

I tried looping the values from config file but I need my code to work like check the key from config file to variables in class file and assign that value  in config file value to the variable

Comment: This might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx. Also, if this is homework you need to say so.

Comment: @GrantWinney Ok, nobody notified me of that before. They still need to say if it's homework though.

Comment: @Shanta please share with us exactly what you tried and where it failed (or failed to satisfy your needs)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below code. Please note I have not run this code. You may need to tweak a bit but this should allow you to iterate through properties in class.

```
public static class Configs
    {
        public static string Key1 {get;set;}
        public static string Key2 {get;set;}


  public static void Main()
  {
    var info = typeof(Configs).GetProperties();
    var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    foreach(var s in info)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Name);  
        foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
        {
                      if(key == s.Name)
                      {
                        s = appSettings[key];
                      }
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: foreach (var s in info)
            {

               foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (key == s.Name)
                    //if(key.Contains(s.Name))
                    {
                        a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].ToString();
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(a);

                    }


                }
             
                Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Made these changes, however still not able to find how to assign the app values to the static variables

Answer (score 0):

```
i got the output: did it as below 
Config file 
<configuration>
  <!--<configSections>
    <section name="QuerySettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    <section name="QuerySettings" type="CustomConfigApp.ConfigHelper, CustomConfigApp"/>

  </configSections>
  <QuerySettings>
    <add key="Qry1" value="Select * from table" />
    <add key="Qry2" value="delete from table" />
  </QuerySettings>-->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Qry1" value="Select * from table" />
    <add key="Qry2" value="delete from table" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

class file 
class sample
    {
          public string Qry1
        { get; set; }
          public string Qry2
        { get; set; }

    }
sample s1 = new sample();
 var QueryConfigKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;S
            if (QueryConfigKey != null)
            {
                foreach (var serverKey in QueryConfigKey.AllKeys)
                {
                    string serverValue = QueryConfigKey.GetValues(serverKey).FirstOrDefault();
                    //Console.WriteLine(serverValue);
                  PropertyInfo propertyInfo = s1.GetType().GetProperty(serverKey);
                  propertyInfo.SetValue(s1, Convert.ChangeType(serverValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType),null);

                }
            }
            string query1 = s1.Qry1;
            string query2 = s1.Qry2;


            Console.WriteLine(query1);
            Console.WriteLine(query2);`enter code here`
            Console.ReadLine();
```